# Where to put complex query that returns a custom object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I have a n-tier solution with these projects in it (simplified for this question):

1. Domain
2. Logic
3. Web

In the "Domain" project I have a "Repositories" namespace and each repository is mapped to a different table in the DB and query its data.
For example - the tables `Customers` and `Orders` will have the corresponding repositories - `CustomersRepository` and `OrdersRepository`.

In the `Logic` project I instantiate these repository objects and call their methods which actually query the DB.

Lets say I want to show a report that display some data from both tables.
This report is constructed by a collection of custom objects - `IList<ReportObject>`.

Now, this `ReportObject` object has no corresponding table in the DB and therefore has no repository object.

**My question:** Where should I put the part of code that actually query the DB and fetch `IList<ReportObject>`? Should it just be in some data controller in the `Logic` layer? or create another repository for the reports? Any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it in a custom repository (as this is not a CRUD operation). You can extend Repository (if you're working with a generic repository) and create one for the query. I wouldn't put queries in other place rather than Repositories since you'll brake the encapsulation of what Repository does. Imagine you change the database in the future, it won't be enough to change the repositories layer. Another reason to not put it there is that the logic will be spread around the application instead of being everything in just one place which simplifies debugging and improvements in the queries.

Hope it helps. Guillermo.

Answer (score 2):

While I think this is mainly a question of opinion, here goes:

You can create a `QueryStore<ReportObject>` instead of a `Repository<ReportObject>`. The name QueryStore is just something I came up with, it's not a coined term.

The function of such a query store would be to, well, run queries on data that is not covered by any repository. It would contain only queries and so can, for instance, easily be implemented using LINQ on top of Entity Framework querying database VIEWs for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The repository pattern is used to encapsulate CRUD operations, but in your case you do not need any Insert or Update. I would put this into the Logic layer and access the DB directly from there.